# What is the radius of convergence of Laurent Series around 0 of $\sin(1/(z-a))$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

$\sin(1/(z-a))$ can be expressed in a Laurent series around $a$, I would like to know how I can shift the centre back to 0.

Answer (score 1):

You don't.

Remember the radius of convergence extends to the nearest pole or essential singularity.  (Unfortunately this theorem does not have a standard name.)

Comment: I asked this because I would like to solve radius of convergence of $\sin(\frac{2}{(z-2i+2)(z-3+i)})=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$. First, I thought I could like to do it by compound angle formula. Besides, I have no idea why this function can be expressed as a holomorphic power series.

Comment: The function is holomorphic near z=0 since it is the composition of a rational map $z\mapsto\frac{2}{(z-\dots)(z-\dots)}$ and an entire function $\sin$.  So you want to find the singularities of this function and look for the closest one to 0.

Comment: I see. So the answer is $\min\{|2i-2|,|3-i|\}=\sqrt8$.Am I correct? Thank you so much for your reminder for holomorphicity around 0, I was struggling to see why it is "entire".

Comment: Yes, that is the correct answer.